# solve equation of erf

Tags: special-functions, transcendental-equations, error-function

I'd like to solve this equation for $\mu$. Is it possible? If not, why?

$$ 2 P = \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{\mu - A}{ \sqrt{2 \sigma^2} } \right) - \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{\mu - B}{\sqrt{2 \sigma^2}} \right) $$

Where $\operatorname{erf}$ is the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). I'm happy to denote the inverse of $\operatorname{erf}$ as $\operatorname{erf^{-1}}$ and use it as such. I hope to solve for $\sigma$ in terms of $\operatorname{erf^{-1}}$.

Assumptions:

- All variables are real numbers.
- $0 < \sigma$.
- $0 < P < 1$.
- $A < B$

---

In lieu of a general solution, I'd be happy with an approximation as long as I can calculate and adjust the precision as necessary.

Comment: If you mean to find a general solution of the form $\mu = h(A,B,P,\sigma)$, no it is not because there is no analytic expression for the error function. Or you want to find $\mu$ given _known_ $A, B, P, \sigma$?

Comment: I was trying to find a general solution. Similar forms (without the inner subtraction) can be solved using $erf^{-1}$.

Comment: What are the relative sizes of $A$, $B$, and $\sigma$?  Is $P$ small?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I don't believe there are any more constraints than I've given above. ( A<B ; $\sigma$ > 0; 0<P<1 )

Comment: See this post, may be it can help you. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547405/product-of-two-complementary-error-functions-erfc/547458#547458 By experimenting a little, you can find the equivalent approximation for negative values.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a solution by formula, no. You can simplify the problem a bit by introducing a new variable $x=(\mu-A)/\sqrt{2\sigma^2}$, so it becomes instead $$2P=\operatorname{erf}(x)-\operatorname{erf}(x-2b)$$ for some suitable $b>0$. You may notice that the right hand side goes to zero as $x\to\pm\infty$, and it is increasing on $(-\infty,b)$ and decreasing on $(b,\infty)$. Its maximum value is achieved at $x=b$. If this is greater than $2P$, there will be two solutions. If it is less than $2P$, there will be no solution.

Comment: Could you explain why there is no symbolic solution?

Comment: @bukzor, analytical solutions to transcendental equations are very rare, so you shouldn't expect one here.  There are, however, various ways to approximate the solutions.

Comment: I've edited the question regarding approximations.

Comment: If the right hand side maximum value is greater than $\large 2P$, there will be two solutions... etc...

Comment: @FelixMarin Argh, of course. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: As @AntonioVargas said. There isn't a symbolic inverse to the error function, so the idea that there would be one for the difference of two error functions is far fetched, to put it mildly. That said, I don't know a *proof* that there isn't one. Such proofs belong to a branch of mathematics I have never paid much attenttion to.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I'm happy to denote the inverse of erf as $erf^{-1}$ and use it as such. I had expected to solve for $\sigma$ in terms of $erf^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the equation, for example, with the regula-falsi-method , if a solution actually exists.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with regula-falsi, but from my brief reading, it only seems to help with numerical solutions, yes?

Comment: Yes, I cannot see a direct method.

Comment: Regula-Falsi is similar to the newton-method, but does not need derivations. It can fail if the roots of a function are multiple, but this does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: The idea is simply to calculate $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ instead of the derivation and work with this approximation.

Comment: It always works, if f is continous and the signs of f(a) and f(b) are different.